# Calling generator function of another js file multiple times and running it synchronously with generators

Tags: javascript, node.js, generator

I have two js files.(nodejs) Both have generator functions. I want to call a generator function of one file from another. Both files have multiple yields and I want to run first yield of file1 and then all the yields of file2.

File1.js

```
function* file1Func(){
console.log("1");
yield* GetFunc();
console.log("2");
yield* file2.file2Func();
console.log("3");
yield* GetFunc2();

}
```

File2.js

```
function* file2Func(){
console.log("A");
yield* func1();
console.log("B");
yield* func2();
console.log("C");
yield* func3();
}
```

Expected Output: 
1 2 A B C 3
Output: 1 2 A 3

Answer (score 1):

Your code is similar in construction to the one below:

```js
function* dummy() {
  yield null;
}

function* func1() {
  console.log(`a`);
  yield* dummy();
  console.log(`b`);
  yield* dummy();
  console.log(`c`);
}

function* func2() {
  console.log(1);
  yield* dummy();
  console.log(2);
  yield* func1();
  console.log(3);
}

for (let x of func2()) {
}
```

It should log your expected output since generator is yielded until it's done. `3` can't be logged before all the logs from `file2Func`.